# xpath for matching DateTime format

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

Im writing an xslt to find all elements with specific Date formats. But the "*match*" statement seems to be a problem.  I need to format this date to a custom format using C# code. Any help would be great..

my XSLT is:

```
  <xsl:template match="text()[.='[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]']">
    <xsl:value-of select="userCSharp:GetFormatedDate(.)" />
  </xsl:template>
```

My Xml is:

```
<Root>
<Name>Don</Name>
<EffectiveDate>01/30/2015</EffectiveDate>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are using XSLT 1.0? If so, try:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[translate(., '123456789', '000000000') = '00/00/0000']">
    <xsl:value-of select="userCSharp:GetFormatedDate(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this matches **any** text node having a pattern of `##/##/####`. It does **not** check for a valid date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. A "date" of `99/99/9999` would pass this test too.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But the date format in some nodes can have '1/30/2015 12:00:00 AM' . What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Well, it depends. You could test for each possible pattern (which could get tedious if you have more than two or three of those) or farm this out to another language. Apparently your processor supports some extensions, so perhaps you can make it use regex.

Comment: P.S. I am puzzled why you need to do this kind of analysis at all. Do you not know the structure of the XML documents that will be processed by your stylesheet?

Comment: my intention is to process these nodes inorder to pass through the xml deserializer which throws exception due to invalid datetime format. It only allows the format like '1961-03-23T00:00:00'

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood me. I asked why do you need to search for nodes that have a string patterned like a date - instead of calling them by name, e.g. `EffectiveDate` in the given example?

Comment: because the xml is returned by another service for which we dont have a control.. so we dont know which node will have these invalid date values..