# Reformat Dates in Xml using xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

```
    <BatchInput>
        <DealInfoObject>
    <DealThirdParty>
                    <ThirdpartyPayment>

                        <DueDate></DueDate> 

                        <DeliveryDate>28/02/2018 12:00:00 AM</DeliveryDate>

                        <AdvanceDate>01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM</AdvanceDate>


                        <ThirdPartySchedule>
                            <DueDate>29/01/2018 12:00:00 AM</DueDate>

                        </ThirdPartySchedule>

                    </ThirdpartyPayment>
<DealThirdParty>

    <DealInfoObject>
<BatchInput>
```

Its some of the xml file that i have iwant to loop on file and change All the date using xslt  To get All Dates Like This format 2018-04-15T00:00:00

Comment: Reformat the XML in the question and show us the XSLT you have been working on so far. A neat question will recieve a neat answer

Comment: And make it valid XML as well - the last three "start elements" should be "end elements".

Comment: It would be best if the author of the XML file fixed it, and generated ISO8601 dates. This file uses locale-specific dates

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that you've accepted an answer that doesn't work, and doesn't use XSLT. Do you not actually need it to handle input in the format you've provided in your sample XML? Do you not care about whether or not it uses XSLT? (If so, why ask for XSLT?)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);


            var dates = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Contains("Date") && ((string)x != string.Empty));

            foreach (var date in dates)
            {
                date.SetValue(((DateTime)date).ToUniversalTime());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) this isn't using XSLT as requested; b) the cast to `DateTime` will fail because LINQ to XML expects the value to be appropriately formatted.

Comment: Why `ToFileTimeUtc` ? The OP isn't asking aboug *file* time. That's the ISO 8601 format. You can get it with `ToString("s")` if you don't want the timezone, `o` if you do. BTW, this assumes you *parse* the text in the first place to get the `DateTime` value

Comment: (Basically, try this code with the XML given in the question, having fixed the close tags - it will fail.)

Comment: Fixed.  This is still a c# solution as the tag says.

Comment: Nope, it's not fixed. This code still fails - and there's more to requirements than just the tags. If you disagree with the requirements, it's worth asking for more details in the comments.

Comment: @jdweng fixed how? You still don't *parse* the text

Comment: @jdweng you need to use `DateTime.Parse()` with a specific locale at least (eg `en-GB`), in order to parse these dates

Comment: The person is using the file in England so en-GB isn't needed.  Only if we try to run in US is it needed.

Comment: You clearly haven't *tried* this code. **It throws an exception.** The conversion from `XElement` to `DateTime` doesn't just call `DateTime.Parse` in a culture-sensitive way - it expects a specific format. And presenting code that only works in a specific culture without presenting *any* warning about it is a really, really bad idea. What makes you think they'll only ever want to execute the code in that culture? Code that relies on the system default culture inappropriately is dangerous.

Comment: Jon : Do you always put en-US in all your DateTime.Parse() methods?

Comment: Are you actually questioning one of the developers of NodaTime if he handles date/times properly? FWIW, every professional C# dev I know would always use one of the `DateTime.Parse` overloads that takes an `IFormatProvider`, even 'out of the box' code analysis in visual studio will always recommend it.

Comment: @jdweng: No, I'd put `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` anywhere that I expect the invariant culture; if I expect a particular culture, I'd specify it when calling `DateTime.Parse`, yes. Now, have you tried the code in your answer using the XML in the question, after fixing the closing elements? I have, and it throws an exception. And I'm in the UK. How do you explain that?

Comment: I think it failing on 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM which may not be a valid date.  December 31,1899 doesn't exist.  Day 0 is Dec 30, 1899, and Day 1 is Jan 1, 1900.

Comment: Um, December 31st 1899 definitely *did* exist, and is representable in `DateTime`. What are you talking about "day 1" etc for? This isn't Excel. 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM is very definitely representable as a `DateTime`. However, just to prove that's not the problem, I changed that date to 01/01/2001 - and just as I suspected, it still failed. It's very unclear to me why you haven't bothered running your own code.

Comment: It Helps in my condition

Comment: @mostafamohamed: Then the XML you've provided can't be the XML you're actually trying to work with, as that would just throw an exception. So basically your question is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The example is ambiguous regarding the input format. Assuming the hours are zero-padded to 2-digit length, you could do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DeliveryDate | AdvanceDate | DueDate">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring(., 1, 2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring(., 4, 2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring(., 7, 4)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="h12" select="substring(., 12, 2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="mmss" select="substring(., 14, 6)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pm" select="contains(.,'P')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="h24" select="$h12 mod 12 + 12*$pm"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$y"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '-00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '-00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h24, 'T00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$mmss"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This needs a little more work if you really have empty date elements.

Comment: A trick I sometimes use to validate date formats is the predicate `[translate(.,'123456789P','000000000A') = '00/00/0000 00:00:00 AM']` (for this question's given date format), although you'd probably need an additional template to handle elements that don't conform to that format.

Comment: @Flynn1179 I use [the same method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37147090/3016153). But OP needs to clarify if this is needed (I suspect it's not).

Answer (score -1):

As you didn't specify the XSLT version, I used version 2.0.

My idea is to convert **each** text node containing a date in your
format to the "proper" format.
If a text node had other content (not matched by the date pattern)
it is left unchanged.

The advantage is that if you had other tags with date,
there will be no need to change the XSLT script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:variable name="mtch"
      select="matches(., '^\d\d/\d\d/\d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [A|P]M$')"/>
    <xsl:if test="$mtch">
      <xsl:variable name="dt" select="xs:date(concat(
        substring(., 7, 4), '-', substring(., 4, 2), '-', substring(., 1, 2)))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="am" as="xs:string" select="substring(., 21, 2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hr" as="xs:string" select="substring(., 12, 2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hri" as="xs:integer" select="
        if ($am = 'AM') then xs:integer($hr) mod 12
        else xs:integer($hr) mod 12 + 12"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hrs" as="xs:string" select="format-number($hri, '00')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="mm" as="xs:string" select="substring(., 15, 2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="ss" as="xs:string" select="substring(., 18, 2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="tm" select="xs:time(concat($hrs, ':', $mm, ':', $ss))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="dtm" select="dateTime($dt, $tm)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$dtm"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($mtch)">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```