# How to change Date from Database Format to American Format in xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In my xml the format for date is like "20151120" its means 20/11/2015 , but it is possible places where its only the year "1997" and have to consider that like "1/1/1997".
I need to do 2 things:

1. If it only appears just year for exemple 2006 it should be "1/1/2006" .
2. I need to change all the Dates to American format.

Thanks very much for the help!!

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<Albums>
    <Album>
        <Name>Empire Burlesque</Name>
        <Artist>Bob Dylan</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>Columbia</Company>
        <Price>10.20</Price>
        <Date>19880610</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Hide your heart</Name>
        <Artist>Bonnie Tylor</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>CBS Records</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>19880509</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Greatest Hits</Name>
        <Artist>Dolly Parton</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>RCA</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>1982</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Still got the blues</Name>
        <Artist>Gary More</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>Virgin redords</Company>
        <Price>10.20</Price>
        <Date>1990</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Eros</Name>
        <Artist>Eros Ramazzotti</Artist>
        <Country>EU</Country>
        <Company>BMG</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>1997</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>25</Name>
        <Artist>Adele</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>XL Recordings</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>20151120</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>1000 Forms of Fear</Name>
        <Artist>Sia</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>RCA Records</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>20140704</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Rattle and Hum</Name>
        <Artist>U2</Artist>
        <Country>EU</Country>
        <Company>Island</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>19881010</Date>
    </Album>
</Albums>
```

XSL:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="country" match="Album" use="Country" />
  <xsl:template match="/Albums">
    <html>
      <body>
        <center>
          <xsl:for-each
            select="Album[generate-id() = generate-id(key('country',Country)[1])]"
          >
            <u style="color: #39c639"
              ><h2 id="{generate-id(Country)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="Country" /></h2
            ></u>
            <table border="2" bgcolor="transparent">
              <tr bgcolor="grey">
                <th>Artist</th>
                <th>Album</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Price</th>
              </tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="key('country',Country)">
                <xsl:sort select="Date" order="ascending" />
                <tr>
                  <td style="color: #ff0000">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Artist" />
                  </td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="Company" /></td>
                  <td>BLABLABLA</td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="Price" /></td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>

              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="yellow">Total Price:</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="yellow">
                  <xsl:value-of
                    select="sum(key('country', 
                            Country)/Price)"
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="yellow">Total Albums:</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="yellow">
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(key('country', Country)/.)" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </center>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? Check the string-length of `Date`: if it's 4, add "1/1/" before it, otherwise rearrange it similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/43910585/3016153.

Comment: BTW, `d/m/y` is not "American format".

Comment: thx for your comment, u right, can u help me with my code? xsl is confuse me

Comment: I can help you with your code when you'll have some. For now, you are asking for someone to write your code for you.This is not a legitimate question.

Comment: becuase i try and failed , i dont ask for all solution , maybe just a direction in code

Comment: I already gave you more than just a direction.